# Using c# to read XML that has nested namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xnamespace

I am trying to extract the following values from this XML using C#.

**Messages** - the inntertext
**success**="true" - just the "true" bit
**status**="Released" - just the "Released" bit

Namespaces are clearly the issue here - but I can't get it right. 
Can someone provide an example of parsing this file here please?

---

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tns:executeCreateLoanIncreaseResponse xmlns:tns="http://api.ws.liq.pisys.com/">
      <CreateLoanIncreaseResponse success="true">
        <OutstandingTransactionAsReturnValue version="1.0" alias="LIBRLC" status="Released" id="5CJB6GS"></OutstandingTransactionAsReturnValue>
        <Messages>
          <Message>CreateLoanIncrease&gt;&gt;Effective date current business date (08-Sep-2016).</Message>
          <Message>CreateLoanIncrease&gt;&gt;Intent Notices have not been generated.</Message>
          <Message>CreateLoanIncrease&gt;&gt;You are about to release this increase.</Message>
        </Messages>
      </CreateLoanIncreaseResponse>
    </tns:executeCreateLoanIncreaseResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement messages = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Messages").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = messages.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<string> strMessages = messages.Elements(ns + "Message").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq2Xml and XPath

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

var success = (bool)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//CreateLoanIncreaseResponse").Attribute("success");
var status = (string)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//OutstandingTransactionAsReturnValue").Attribute("status");
var messages = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Message").Select(x => (string)x.Value).ToList();
```